# Python: Plotting Slices of Time Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a two column dataset, one with daily dates from 1990-2015 and one with electrical output. I want to plot certain years worth of power output, the daily average electrical output for the entire dataset and +-1 standard error shaded around that mean all on one line graph. However, as it stands now, I get one plot for the mean and then 1 plot for each year (i.e. 8 separate plots). I'm attempting to do this in Pandas, but help in either NumPy or Pandas would be great.

My dataset and current code is listed below:

```
# Dummy data since the actual file is very large.
dates = pd.date_range(start='01-01-1990',end='12-31-2015',freq='D')
vols = np.random.random_integers(0,60000,9496)
full = np.array([dates,vols]).T

yrs = [1990,1994,1998,2002,2006,2010,2014]
mons = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']

data = pd.DataFrame(full,names=['date','elec'])
data['yr'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date']).year
data['mon'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date']).month
data['day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['date']).day

mean = data.groupby(['mon','day']).mean().reset_index()
std  = data.groupby(['mon','day']).std().reset_index()

power = data[data['yr'].isin(yrs)]
pwryear = power.groupby('yr')

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize = (14,5))

ax1.plot(mean.elec,'k-',lw=4)
pwryear.plot()
ax1.set_title('Merrimack River floods at Lowell, MA')
ax1.set_ylabel('Discharge [m$^{3}$ s$^{-1}$]')
ax1.set_xticks([0,30,59,90,120,151,181,212,243,273,304,334])
ax1.set_xticklabels(mons)
ax1.set_xlim(0,365)
ax1.grid()
ax1.legend(loc=2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing `pwryear = power.groupby('yr')` with:

```
# create a column that includes month and day, but not year
# this will be the x-axis
data['mon_day'] = data.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%m-%d'))
# transform your dataframe to have one column per year
pwryear = power[['mon_day', 'elec', 'yr']].set_index(['mon_day', 'yr']).unstack(1)
pwryear.columns = pwryear.columns.droplevel(0)
```

Now, when you run `pwryear.plot()`, you will get one line per year.

To get the shading for std, you will want to change

```
mean = data.groupby(['mon','day']).mean().reset_index()
std  = data.groupby(['mon','day']).std().reset_index()
```

to

```
mean = data.groupby('mon_day').mean()
std  = data.groupby('mon_day').std()
```

Then, do:

```
ax1.fill_between(mean.index, mean.elec - std.elec, mean.elec + std.elec)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I do want the annual plots, though. I just don't want them all separate. I want them on the same graph as the annual daily average with associated standard deviation.

Comment: Okay. Then you'll want to make each year into a separate column in the same dataframe. You can do that using some set_index() and unstack() magic. I'll update my answer.

Comment: That would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: This all works great except that the mon_day goes in numerical alphabetical(?) order, meaning that index 0 is associated with 1/1, but index 1 is 1/10, index 2 is 1/11 and so on and so forth

Comment: Oops. It's now corrected by properly padding with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure pandas graphing is just a wrapper around Matplotlib.  If that's the case, you would pass in your series as lists of x coordinates and y coordinates, (alternating) to render multiple series on the same plot.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot

Comment: I've tried something like this, but the x-axis ends up being the index position of the 'elec' and because the years are so spread apart it will plot 1990 and then a large amount of whitespace for 91, 92, 93 and then 1994 and so on.

Comment: You may need to adjust your dataset to have the same approximate number of coordinates in each time period.  See if pandas.DataFrame.resample() helps.